# Send child url to parent when closing popup window in javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

My popup window is basically an authorization form that sends back a url when the authentication is successful. Now what happens is that the response url gets shown in the popup window url box. I want to be able to send this response url to the parent window and extract the tokens from it. I tried window.opener and what not but I can't get the response url be sent to the parent on closing the popup window. Someone got any ideas on how to get this done?

Thanks

Comment: Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Comment: The pages have to come from the same origin. Then window.opener should be available in onbeforeunload